# what is ultrasonic based slam

Tags: slam, computer-vision

i am confused about SLAM implementation, and i need your advise to organize my mind.
Fist let me say that i have to generate 2D map, what is in this case the SLAM input? is it like (x1,y1),(x2,y2)...(xn,yn)?
Second, if we have to generate 3D map, what is the real input of slam, Does it is (x1,y1,z1)..?

Many SLAM implementations use LIDAR, and i have to know the data form that it provides, but really i have no LIDAR, i have to use ultrasonic sensors to map environment, how much does this speak seem logical ?
If  we generate a 3d surrounding points from specific ultrasonic sensors configuration, does these 3d points enough to build 3D map?

Comment: It's possible. However, it's not the purpose of the ultrasónica sensor. It's designed for measuring distances, not creating maps. Moreover, you'd have many inaccuracies comparing to LIDAR

Answer (score 1):

usually ultrasonic sensors are not precise

Using an ultrasonic sensor will not very good for large environments. It is very imprecise and SLAM algorithms accumulate error intrinsically it my be enough for simple indoor environments but you'd better use a lidar or a camera (cameras are cheap)